# Problems accessing Laravel api from Vue(Nuxt js) app in docker

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, docker-compose, nuxt.js

Currently I'm working on Nuxt js app that should connect to backend api made in Laravel.

The problem is that every request that is sent to the api via axios fails with one of this errors(Depending on the API_URL I use):

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT API_URL

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED API_URL

Example request:

```
axios.get(process.env.API_URL + 'api/something') ...
```

I just cant figure out what API_URL to use, here are some of the things I tried:

- http://172.19.0.4:8080/ -> this is the IP address of api container I've got from ***docker inspect {containername}***
- http://172.19.0.4/ -> also tried without the port, actually all of these were tried with/without port
- http://localhost:8080/
- http://app/ -> app is the service name and alias of api in docker-compose.yml

API_URL is defined **nuxt.config.js**:

```
env: {
    'API_URL': 'http://172.19.0.4:8080/'
},
```

In the browser http://localhost:8080/ opens the API and http://localhost:8081/ opens the webapp.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app: #backend api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.debug
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      APP_URL: http://localhost:8080 #api
      WEB_URL: http://localhost:8081 #vue app
    volumes:
      - ./project:/app
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    networks:
      project-network-frontend:
        aliases:
          - app
      project-network-backend:
        aliases:
          - app

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:3000"
    environment:
      - API_URL=http://app:8080/
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    networks:
      project-network-frontend:
        aliases:
          - frontend
    volumes:
      - "../frontendproject:/app"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true        

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3300:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./debug/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ***
      MYSQL_USER: ***
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****
    networks:
      project-network-frontend:
        aliases:
          - mysql
      project-network-backend:
        aliases:
          - mysql

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./debug/redis/data:/data
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    networks:
      project-network-frontend:
        aliases:
          - redis
      project-network-backend:
        aliases:
          - redis
networks:
  project-network-frontend:
    name: project-network-frontend
  project-network-backend:
    name: project-network-backend
```

Folder structure:

- ROOT

  - backend

    - docker-compose.yml
    - backendproject(laravel folder)
    - dockerfile
  - frontend

    - frontendproject(nuxt/vue folder)
    - dockerfile

I've also tried setting up axios baseURL like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368891/7657853

Comment: there are several things u can try to debug this. Start commenting out all the network stuff in your compose file (docker will create one for u & attach all the containers to it). Then make sure you can hit the backend at localhost:8080 from your host. The exec into your front end and try to ping app (your backend). Then, if memory serves me right, nuxt does SSR so depending on wether your code is running on the server or the browser, you will either have to hit app:8080 or localhost:8080. Note that if your code is running on the browser process.env.API may be empty. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
env: {
    'API_URL': 'http://docker.for.win.localhost:8080/'
},
```

But had to change it to this after latest docker update:

```
'API_URL': 'http://host.docker.internal:8080/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `baseURL` for an Axios module in the Nuxt configuration file> nuxt.config.js.

```
axios: {
   baseUrl: process.env.API_URL,
   credentials: true
},
```